# VM892:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, reactjs, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm presently working on a phx / phoenix API written in Elixir.  And I have created a frontend for the API using React.js.  However, I'm getting the below error message in the JS console of the browser.

I have successfully created a user using Postman, so I'm 99% sure the error isn't with the phx project, but rather somewhere with the React project.

I have both the [frontend](https://github.com/ipatch/kegcopr-frontend) and [backend](https://github.com/ipatch/kegcopr_api) hosted on github.  And a `.env` file will need to be created in the root of the React project with the below line,

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:4000/api
```

and was working my way through the [following tutorial](https://medium.com/@benhansen/lets-build-a-slack-clone-with-elixir-phoenix-and-react-part-1-project-setup-3252ae780a1).

Any and all help would greatly be appreciated.

[image: error message]

Comment: Which index.js files are in that stacktrace? There are tons of files named `index.js` in the frontend app. Please also include the relevant code that throws the error in the question itself so that the question makes sense even after that repository is not online for any reason in the future.

Comment: The top most `index.js` file in the stacktrace is the `/src/api/index.js`

Comment: What's the output of this in the JS console: `localStorage.getItem('token')`?

Comment: @Dogbert the ouput of the above command you requested is,
`"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJVc2VyOjEiLCJleHAiOjE0ODcyODI4ODcsImlhdCI6MTQ4NDY5MDg4NywiaXNzIjoiUGhvZW5peENoYXQiLCJqdGkiOiIwNzFlYzgwYi0wZmYzLTQyYzgtODA3Mi1kNzViZmVhZTg4NWEiLCJwZW0iOnt9LCJzdWIiOiJVc2VyOjEiLCJ0eXAiOiJhY2Nlc3MifQ.NsuqH50HooK8vjFfHtPH9iXSykZ9oYA0ul4b_C5fQtpu_zFvNNy-skcv9HI2i25X-NlB-9xOr-xzh2abnrpYUw"`

Comment: Yeah, that's not valid JSON. You probably have a `localStorage.setItem` that does not do `JSON.stringify` on the input somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem could be TBH, I'm reviewing the tutorial I was working through, and as far as I can tell my `src/api/index.js` looks identical to this, https://github.com/bnhansn/sling/blob/master/web/src/api/index.js

Comment: Can you try clearing localStorage and re-running the app? Maybe the token was saved that way during development.

Comment: @Dogbert thank you very much, AGAIN :-)  The issue appeared to be localStorage related.  Feel free to move your comment into an answer, and I'll accept it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of `localStorage.getItem("token")` being

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJVc2VyOjEiLC‌​JleHAiOjE0ODcyODI4OD‌​csImlhdCI6MTQ4NDY5MD‌​g4NywiaXNzIjoiUGhvZW‌​5peENoYXQiLCJqdGkiOi‌​IwNzFlYzgwYi0wZmYzLT‌​QyYzgtODA3Mi1kNzViZm‌​VhZTg4NWEiLCJwZW0iOn‌​t9LCJzdWIiOiJVc2VyOj‌​EiLCJ0eXAiOiJhY2Nlc3‌​MifQ.NsuqH50HooK8vjF‌​fHtPH9iXSykZ9oYA0ul4‌​b_C5fQtpu_zFvNNy-skc‌​v9HI2i25X-NlB-9xOr-x‌​zh2abnrpYUw
```

suggests that for some reason, the app stored the token without passing it through `JSON.stringify`, and calling `JSON.parse` on this string throws the `Unexpected token e` error, as expected.

I did not see any `localStorage.setItem` without `JSON.stringify` in the current code, so the token was probably stored like that in a previous version of the app. You should try clearing it manually and logging in again.

Answer (score 3):

When we get the non-JSON response, we get such error..
To avoid such error, mention the responseType: Text in your api endpoint call.

This will work,

```
 return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/login`, user, {responseType: 'text'});
```

This will not work(If you mention type),

```
  return this.http.post<string>(`${environment.apiUrl}/login`, user, {responseType: 'text'});
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message usually means you're getting a non-JSON response. If you look at the raw response in the Network tab of your debugger, you should be able to see what you're getting back from the server.